# routerLink pass component instance's data as state

Tags: angular, angular7, breadcrumbs, angular-routerlink

In my application I use breadcrumbs this way:

```
 <div class="breadcrumb">

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="back" (click)="goBack($event);">Back</a>
    <div class="">
      <h3>{{ pagename.label }}</h3>
      <div *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs" class="bread-link-container texted">
        <a [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url]">
          {{ breadcrumb.label }}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>
```

I have component A from which the user can navigate to component B; then, when from B you go back to A, B needs to send data as `state` to component A. Like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['path-to-A'], {
            state: {
              data: myData
            }
          });
```

Now, when the user goes back B->A by pressing a custom BACK button I can pass the state because I manually call router.navigate. The problem is when the user clicks on the routerLink of the breadcrumb the state information is not sent and component A complains about this.
I've seen that I can send the `state` through routerLink, like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [state]="{tracingId: 123}">
  link to user component
</a>
```

but I need to get the name of the property and the value that I want to pass as state from the component which I'm navigating from. How can this be done?

Comment: cant you bind myData the same way to your state as you do in the manual call.  [state]="myData" ?

Comment: The breadcrumb is a sibling of component B and is repeated in various components, so I can't send to the breadcrumb the data from the component and the breadcrumb doesn't know which component it has as sibling